# Fill remaining horizontal space (or max-width) AND wrap on min-width

Tags: css-float, fluid-layout, css, flexbox

`#fit` and `#wrap` illustrate two different **behaviors** that I want to have for **one element** depending on the situation. The element should work like `#fit` if there is room, but should work like `#wrap` if there is not enough room.

http://jsfiddle.net/benstenson/dN8VJ/

```
<div id="print">
    Printable
</div>
<div id="fit">
    Looks good on same line
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    Looks good on new line
</div>
```

css

```
body{overflow:hidden;padding:1em;}
div
{
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    float:left;
    height:1in;
    margin:.5em;text-align:center;line-height:1in;
    white-space:nowrap;box-shadow:0 0 .5em gray;
}
#print
{
    width:5in;
    background-color:black; color:white;
}
#fit
{
    /* when on same line
       Size to min-width
       OR fill remaining space
       (like flexible box style).
       Either way is fine.
    */
    min-width:3in;
    background-color:gold;
}
#wrap
{
    /* when wrapped to next line */
    /* fill 100% OR to max width */
    width:100%;
    min-width:3in;
    max-width:5in;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for *is* Flexbox, but most browsers that support Flexbox *don't* support wrapping.  The ones that do are IE10, Chrome, and Opera.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/lqrGB

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="print">
    Printable
  </div>
  <div id="either">
    Looks good on either line
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
}
.container div {
  height: 1in;
  margin: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1in;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em gray;
}

#print {
  /*-webkit-flex: 1 5in;
  -ms-flex: 1 5in;
  flex: 1 5in;*/
  width: 5in;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#either {
  -webkit-flex: 1 3in;
  -ms-flex: 1 3in;
  flex: 1 3in;
  max-width: 5in;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, I think you can achieve what you want with `inline-block`.

You'll need to put your content in a paragraph inside another div, like this:

```
<div class="wrap-or-fit">
  <p>This is where your content goes.</p>
</div>
```

Then just set the `min-width` and `max-width` properties on the paragraph, as well as `display:inline-block`.

```
.wrap-or-fit > p {
  max-width:5in;
  min-width:3in;
  display:inline-block;
  ...
}
```

If the content fits on a single line less than 3 inches wide, the container will expand to be at least 3 inches. If the content is wider than 5 inches, it is forced to wrap within a container of exactly 5 inches.

If the content is between 3 and 5 inches, the container width matches the content width. I'm not sure if that is what you wanted, but that may be the best you can do.

You can see an expanded example showing both narrow and wide content samples, and styling that more closely matching your original example in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KhpLu).